# Azure VM disk per drive SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-disk-throughput

On an Azure VM, does it matter if I partition a large disk into multiple drives (to hopefully be more contiguous - not sure if it'd matter virtually) where if space is needed, it'd then need to be a dynamic allocation (as far as OS)?  Or should I generally stick to a disk per drive when expansion would seem necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in Azure Vm you should pool disks (P30 or P40) to achieve  higher level of troughput. If you need different drives i suggest creating differend storage pools.

This way gives you better IO performance that usually is great for databases, but gives you difficulties to enlarge drives. Enlarge drives inside a storage pool is not possible, but you can add more disks to the pool as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to ask our Cloud Architect to check on the underlying configuration, since it's already stood up, and read up on the topic a bit before marking the answer.  Appreciate your response.

Comment: As far as the original question, at the OS level, any feedback you could supplement your initial response with?

Comment: .... to hopefully be more contiguous - not sure if it'd matter virtually ...
this dosen't matter in Azure VM. Better to have separated disk pools for multiple drives to increase # of options and reduce work in case of architectural changes